# SQL Server EXISTS query to determine relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

**Foo**

```
   FooId INT PRIMARY KEY
```

**FooRelationship**

```
   FooRelationshipId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
   FooParentId INT FK
   FooChildId INT FK
```

How would I write a query that would return every id from Foo and the status the record (whether it is a parent, a child or neither).

Rules:

- A foo will only be a parent or a child or neither.
- A foo can be the parent of multiple different foos.
- A foo can not be the child of more than one foo.

I originally wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
    FooId,
    CASE
        WHEN Parent.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Parent'
        WHEN Child.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Child'
        ELSE 'Neither'
    END
FROM Foo F
LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Parent ON F.FooId = Parent.FooParentId
LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Child ON F.Fooid = Child.FooParentId
```

This is broken because if a Foo is a parent to two other Foos then it returns that id twice.

How can I rewrite this to either not use a join or use an EXISTS or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DISTINCT` - this is a good use case for it.  You can't use `EXISTS` since you actually need to pull the data from both tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FooId,
    CASE
        WHEN Parent.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Parent'
        WHEN Child.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Child'
        ELSE 'Neither'
    END
FROM Foo F
LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Parent ON F.FooId = Parent.FooParentId
LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Child ON F.Fooid = Child.FooParentId
```

I'm not normally a big fan of `DISTINCT` because it's often used to hide messy data, but I think this is an appropriate use for it.

Be warned it may slow things down dramatically if you are using it across a large number of fields and rows.

If you want to get just these values and then populate the rest of the rows as well, you can do a subquery for the relationship logic:

```
SELECT s.FooID, s.Relationship, T.*
FROM Table T
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
    FooId,
    CASE
        WHEN Parent.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Parent'
        WHEN Child.FooRelationshipId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Child'
        ELSE 'Neither' 
    END as [Relationship]
   FROM Foo F
   LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Parent ON F.FooId = Parent.FooParentId
   LEFT JOIN FooRelationship Child ON F.Fooid = Child.FooParentId) s
ON s.FooId = t.FooID
```

Comment: Is there a better way you would write this query. I am kind of worried about performance because there are quite a few rows in this table and it has around 30-40 columns?

Comment: @Dismissile I would need more info, but one option would be to use your example (narrow) query as a subselect, and JOIN on that.  Then you could get the `FooID, Relationship` information without getting the rest of the rows, and `JOIN` to that.  I'll post an example.

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot.

Comment: @Dismissile happy to help.  Just don't use `DISTINCT` too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SELECT DISTINCT FooID, ...`

it will return just one `FooID` in case that you mentioned as problematic

Comment: It will actually return only one row per unique combination of row values, not just `FooID`

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your existing query to do a `select distinct` instead of a plain `select`.